General solution a population growth difference equation
Hi guys I've been struggling with this for two weeks I finally admitted defeat and am looking for help.
I need to find the general solutions to the following difference
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
U(n+1) =U(n)^2 −10 \\
U(0) = 4
\end{array}
\right.
$$

This seems to be an isolated problem. Please, share your thoughts and ideas on the problem to help contributors navigate you to the solution.

I tried solving it by assuming U(0) is a in the formula that is usually used for this type of thing: U(n) = a^n(U(0) - 1/(1-b)) + 1/(a-b). Then I tried expanding the formula until realised that U(0)>2^n was a part of the equation. Then I tried creating quadratic equations to satisfy this and it just didn't work

Not sure what sort of solution you are hoping for.  This is A099941, though that doesn't help much.

Thank you, I'm basically looking for this formulae in terms of U(n) and U(0) with U(n) being the subject of the equation

Are you sure such a representation exists? More often than not, it's not the case.

I don’t know but that’s what I’m being asked to do

You haven't found a closed form, because it doesn't exists in that case. Indeed, only two types of quadratic recurrence relations possess a closed form (see this answer of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627010/recurrence-relation-a-n-frac12-a-n-12-4/4627131#4627131).

From A099941, and a little research in the linked Aho & Sloane paper, we have for $n \ge 2,$ $$U(n) = \left\lceil c^{2^n} \right\rceil$$ where $c = 2.25389493024591818564987473260518595497528199646373551430047151255211$.
